# .htaccess errordocument 404 for .htm and .html

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, 404

My `.htaccess` is displayed below.

It catches `example.com/abcnonsense` and sends it to my error page - `404error.htm`.

But fails to catch `example.com/abcnonsense.htm` or `example.com/abcnonsense.html`.

In these cases it redirects to my home page.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404error.htm

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myexample\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ / [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.htm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.x?h?t?ml?)$ /cgi-bin/cms.cgi?a=pg&p=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*\.x?h?t?ml?)$ /cgi-bin/cms.cgi?a=pg&p=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
> ```

Because the very last line rewrites all `.htm` and `.html` requests to your `/cgi-bin/cms.cgi` script. Any 404's that result from `.htm` or `.html` requests would therefore need to be managed by this script. In other words, your CMS needs to manage the 404, not Apache.

**EDIT:** Unless... your CMS only works on `.htm` or `.html` files that physically exist on the filesystem? (Although I doubt this.)

Comment: What happens if I remove the last line? Would that solve it?

Comment: Ok i tried that and the whole site went down.

Comment: What do i need to put in the cms.cgi to catch the 404 and send it to my error page - 404error.htm ?

Comment: Yes, if you remove that line then it will resolve your immediate problem of triggering your 404 ErrorDocument, but none of your URLs will be routed through your CMS script, so the "site will go down". Unfortunately, exactly how you would need to edit your `cms.cgi` script to handle such errors is out of scope for this site - we would need to see your entire script. We don't even know what language it is written in? Does it connect to a database? etc. etc.

Comment: looks like it is written in Perl

Comment: There is this line - $dbh = &db_connect(); so I assume it connects to the database

Comment: However, you probably shouldn't be trying to edit the script in such a way. Doesn't the "CMS" already handle a 404 response? You should probably be customising that response, rather than trying to use Apache's `ErrorDocument` here. Your `/404error.htm` document might not even produce the desired result if read directly using your CMS (which is what you would need to do, the `ErrorDocument` directive itself won't apply here).